# Java 8u201: no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

After updating to Java 8u201 I am getting an exception when trying to connect from a SSLSocket to a SSLServerSocket. The exception states that these two clients have 'no cipher suites in common' (even on the same machine with same cipher suites enabled).

The client receives the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1533)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:95)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    ...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:750)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    ...
```

And the server this one:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:306)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1127)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:814)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:221)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
```

---

In the past (Java 8u192) the following code worked fine for me

```
// This is how I create the SSLSocket
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(factory.getSupportedCipherSuites());


// This is how I create the SSLServerSocket
SSLServerSocketFactory factory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
final SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(port, limit, address);
serverSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(factory.getSupportedCipherSuites());
```

**My Question:** Shouldn't the Client and Server agree on one CipherSuite without specifying this explicitly?

Below I added the list of all supported cipher suites on my machine. Both (client and server) have the same supported cipher suties:

[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]

Comment: To answer your actual question: yes. You should not enable all supported cipher suites. The explanation for the error is probably that the server couldn't find its private key.

Comment: @user207421+ and the error happened now because below 8u201 it allowed insecure 'anonymous' suites with no authentication which don't _need_ a server privatekey+cert(chain): see https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u201-relnotes-5209271.html at "TLS anon and NULL Cipher Suites are Disabled"

Comment: Which in turn means that prior to this your application hasn't been secure at all, as TLS is not deemed secure without peer authentication. @dave_thompson_085

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you for your suggestions and hints!

Okay so I have to generate a certificate and pass it over to the server on startup?
Even if I want to communicate in my private network I have to generate a certificate for the server (which the clients need to recognize as valid) to encrypt the communication?